# How to port QT QVariantMap to STL C++?

Tags: c++, qt, stl, containers, porting

I want to port QVariant and QVariantMap to STL c++.

I tried with boost variant and C++17 variant. I'm not able to access the values of map which is in variant type. I have different datatype values for each key. I need to use heterogeneous container in c++. How to access the variant values without specifying the datatype.

Could you please guide me to solve this problem.

```
map<string, variant<int, string>> my_map ;
my_map.insert({"ab", 7676});
my_map.insert({"cd", "stringval"});

for(auto itr = my_map.cbegin();itr!= my_map.cend();++itr){
    if(itr->first == "ab"){
        cout<<get<int>(itr->second)<<endl;//How to access the value If I don't know the datatype of value of my_map?
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> How to access the variant values without specifying the datatype.

You can't directly. If you have an operation applicable to all of the contained datatypes, you can `std::visit` the variant, and apply that operation.

```
std::visit([](auto value){ std::cout << value << std::endl; }, itr->second);
```

[See it live](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5421d0c797ae38c7)

Comment: Thanks, Can we access the containers also like list<string> etc?

Comment: @Sirisha [`std::visit`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant/visit) *requires* a callable that accepts each type the variant can hold.

Comment: @thanks Is there any other alternative for this type of problem in cpp?